# Display legend in map chart using d3 in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, charts

I have facing problem while displaying legend in d3.
i tried this code but unable to got result, display only square box.

link will be in comment.

Help me guys for display legend.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZH2Lq5iIKGZxIOHDE5Hc?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

Firstly...

```
d3.append("g")
```

...is not a function. It should be:

```
d3.select("svg").append("g")
```

Secondly, you don't have any property called `name` in your `uStatePaths` array, but you have one called `n`. Thus, it should be:

```
.attr("data-legend",function(d) {return d.n})//not d.name
```

Here is your updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/63wpE1A4XIbkLoW7Cj9O?p=preview

**PS**: you just edited your original plunker, which makes my answer's references wrong. Don't do that. If you want to make changes in the plunker, fork it instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. but one question more can we have value in legend like color , StateName  and Values ?

Comment: I never used this `d3.legend.js` plugin. Maybe you can check its documentations.

Comment: I got Solution for display value also :)